# Search code in WordPress date range (required)

Tags: wordpress, date, search, range

Please provide me with a code that I can do in WordPress by date range search .
The post_type is changed .

Example :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi json, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than including links to images, can you describe in words exactly what you are trying to achieve - this makes sure that the question is searchable and understandable on its own within the site.

Comment: Hi, I want to create a search form that allows it to search by date range did.    
But I'm not fluent in PHP .

Comment: What code do you already have? We can't write an entire plugin or theme for you.

Comment: The code I want to be able to do I search by date range

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'year'  => 2016,
        'month' => 08,
        'day'   => 01,
        'compare'   => '>=',
    ),
    array(
        'year'  => 2016,
        'month' => 08,
        'day'   => 31,
        'compare'   => '<=',
    ),
),
'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Paste values in fields like date range by the user .        
Your code has been set at constant values .       
Please php code and html to put in my possession

Comment: If your date format is Y-m-d $arr1 = explode("-", $date1); then $year = $arr1[0]; and etc.

Comment: Please complete the form code html and php search by date range when I put the ball .    
Unfortunately, I'm not the dominant programming language PHP